# how to store a date, and then check to see if another date matches that date

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out dates in Java and am completely lost. Do I use Date? Use epoch time? Gregorian Calendar?

Let's say I have a want to store a date, then later compare it to other dates. For example, I've stored a date "10/27/2013". Then, I want to later compare it to dates entered later to see if a later date is identical to "10/27/2013", or if just the day, year, or month matches? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It depends the level you want to check. What, for you, is a matching date? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I would recommend checking out [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: Java `Date` is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Unless you have a particular need of `Calendar`, using the default `Calendar` (`Calendar.getInstance`) should be sufficient for manipulation.  Date comparison can be done with `Date#equals`, `Date#before` and `Date#after`, but this includes the time value of the `Date`, so formatting the `Date` objects to a `String` might produce better results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the `java.util.Date` class is not just a `Date`, it should be more accurately called a `TimeStamp` because it includes time information.

To compare to `java.util.Date` instances you need write a custom `Comparator` that ignores the time information, or what I like to do is ZERO out the time information.

Here are some code snippets to manage normalizing any `java.util.Date` object so that the time information is *zeroed out*.

All of these are static methods on a class called `DateUtil`

```
public static boolean equalsIgnoreTime(final Date d1, final Date d2)
{
    return DateUtil.zeroTime(d1).equals(DateUtil.zeroTime(d2));
}
```

depends on the following static method:

```
public static Date zeroTime(final Date date)
{
    return DateUtil.setTime(date, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

which depends on:

```
public static Date setTime(final Date date, final int hourOfDay, final int minute, final int second, final int ms)
{
    final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(date);
    gc.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    gc.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    gc.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
    gc.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, ms);
    return gc.getTime();
}
```

Your references to *storage* are not clear, so I don't know how to address how or what you are storing or where you are storing the data, but if you are doing the comparisons in Java code, the storage is pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The Date and Calendar classes bundled with Java 7 and earlier are notoriously bad. Those in the know instead use a third-party open-source library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Joda-Time has methods to convert between its objects and the Java platform's `Date` class. Use when you need to inter-operate with other software expecting a `Date` instance.

If using Java 8, use the new [JSR 310 Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which was inspired by Joda-Time. Some folks attempted to back-port a JSR 310 implementation to Java 7; I don’t know if they succeeded.

Here is same sample code using Joda-Time to demonstrate some of what you asked. Use at your own risk; I did not thoroughly think it through nor did I test.

```
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

// Joda-Time - The popular alternative to Sun/Oracle's notoriously bad date, time, and calendar classes bundled with Java 7 and earlier.
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

// Joda-Time will become outmoded by the JSR 310 Date and Time API introduced in Java 8.
// JSR 310 was inspired by Joda-Time but is not directly based on it.
// http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310

// By default, Joda-Time produces strings in the standard ISO 8601 format.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

// Capture one moment in time.
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
System.out.println("Now: " + now);

// Calculate approximately same time yesterday.
org.joda.time.DateTime yesterday = now.minusDays(1);
System.out.println("Yesterday: " + yesterday);

// Compare dates. A DateTime includes time (hence the name).
// So effectively eliminate the time by setting to start of day.
Boolean isTodaySameDateAsYesterday = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay().isEqual(yesterday.withTimeAtStartOfDay());
System.out.println("Is today same date as yesterday: " + isTodaySameDateAsYesterday);

org.joda.time.DateTime halloweenInUnitedStates = new org.joda.time.DateTime(2013, 10, 31, 0, 0); // Uses default time zone.
Boolean isFirstMomentSameDateAsHalloween = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay().isEqual(halloweenInUnitedStates.withTimeAtStartOfDay());
System.out.println("Is now the same date as Halloween in the US: " + isFirstMomentSameDateAsHalloween);

// Wait a moment.
try {
    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(300);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// See if new moment is on the same date as previous moment.
// May not be same date if we rolled over the stroke of midnight.
org.joda.time.DateTime aMomentLater = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
Boolean isFirstMomentSameDateAsAMomentLater = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay().isEqual(aMomentLater.withTimeAtStartOfDay());
System.out.println("Is first moment the same date as a moment later: " + isFirstMomentSameDateAsAMomentLater);
```

Example run…

```
Now: 2013-10-27T20:36:21.406-07:00
Yesterday: 2013-10-26T20:36:21.406-07:00
Is today same date as yesterday: false
Is now the same date as Halloween in the US: false
Is first moment the same date as a moment later: true
```

---

**Never** ever store a date as text like you mentioned: `I've stored a date "10/27/2013".`

Whenever possible, keep the date as a date object such as `DateTime` in Joda-Time or as a database's native date-time format. If you must [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) a date-time to text, use a reliable and predictable format, with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) being the obvious choice. That format is the default in Joda-Time as you can see in example run above.

Answer (score -2):

Use the below code to format the date and store in database. Use the same format for the new date and perform comparison.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date date = null;
```